# stable_baselines3 evaluate_policy doens't render window even though render = 'True'

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

There is my code

```
env = make_atari_env(enviroment_name, n_envs=1, seed=0)
env = VecFrameStack(env, n_stack=4)
model = A2C.load('Training/Saved Models/A2C_Breakout_Model', env)
evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=10, render=True)
```

When I was using gym.make() I could just pass render_mode = 'human' and all would work. But in this case there is no such parameter.

Tried to use gym.make() instead of make_atari_env occured error

Comment: There is some kind of [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77532840/render-doesnt-work-for-gym-environment) , but anyway, rendered window is too small and  why evalute_policy does not render anything

Comment: This may be something related to your *gym* version. I also encountered this when having to downgrade gym to 0.21.0, because that was the version that worked for me with *stable baselines*' `make_atari()` and `wrap_deepmind()`. For 0.21.0, `env.render("human")` works